# Upload New Library on Python

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I need to deploy a library in Python and try to `pip install` it using pip, but after uploading the library it is installing only info file: "oauth2clientz.egg-info".

Note: My library name is **oauth2clientz**:

The Steps that I follow:

1. Create a folder name it oauth2clientz.
2. Create License.txt file put my own license inside.
3. Create Manifest.in file and write this code:

   ```
   global-include *.txt *.py
   ```
4. Create setup.py file and write this code:

   ```py
   from setuptools import setup, find_packages

   setup(
   name='oauth2clientz',
   version='0.0.1',
   description='oauth2clientzskproject',
   long_description='outh2client',
   long_description_content_type='text/plain',
   url='https://github.com/sukan/oauth2clientz',
   author='sukan',
   author_email='sukanpp@gmail.com',
   classifiers=[
       'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
       'Intended Audience :: Developers',
       'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
       'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
       'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
       'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
       'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
       'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
   ],
   keywords='oauth2clientz project',
   )
   ```
5. Create new folder inside this folder, name it oauth2clientz and put all my library files inside it include (`__init__.py`).
6. Go to cmd to the first oauth2clientz folder and enter:

   ```sh
   python setup.py sdist
   ```
7. It will generate these two folders: "oauth2clientz.egg-info" and "dist".
8. Finally, Enter to cmd:

   ```
   twipe upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*

   enter username:

   enter password:
   ```

Done it is deployed to Python org but when I install it using `pip install oauth2clientz` it's only installing this info folder: "oauth2clientz.egg-info", it didn't install my libraries that I add to the oauth2clientz folder.

why? What is the wrong part of my work? Should I add any thing to the `setup.py` file?

Comment: You are missing `packages=` in your `setup()` call.

Comment: what should I put packages=find_packages()? or packages=<the name of all my .py file>
@KlausD.

Comment: Packages != .py files. So I guess you start with the first option, it knows what to do.

Answer (score 2):

as @Klaus D stated, your are missing `packages`.

based on last best practises (`src layout`, `pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg` ..),  typically your package should have the following structure:

```
oauth2clientz/

  .. src/
     .. oauth2clientz/
        .. __ init__.py  # HERE you declare the version of your package
        .. module-1.py
        .. module-2.py

  .. tests/
     .. __ init__.py
     .. test_module_1.py
     .. test_module_2.py

  .. .editconfig
  .. .gitignore
  .. LISENCE
  .. MANIFEST.in
  .. README.md
  .. setup.cfg
  .. pyproject.toml
```

#### src/oauth2clientz/__ init__.py

```
from module_1 import [..]
from module_2 import [..]


VERSION = (0, 0, 1, 'dev1')
__version__ = '.'.join(map(str, VERSION))


# YOU business logic 
# ..
```

#### MANIFEST.in

```
# https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/
graft src/oauth2clientz
global-exclude __pycache__
global-exclude *.py[cod]
```

#### setup.cfg

```
# https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html
[metadata]
name = oauth2clientz
version = attr: oauth2clientz.__version__  # use 'attr:' helper get the version from the package 
description = oauth2 clientz project
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
author = sukan
author_email = sukanpp@gmail.com
# maintainer =
# maintainer_email =
license = BSD-3-Clause
license_file = LICENSE
# license_files = LICENSES/*
url = https://github.com/sukan/oauth2clientz
download_url = https://github.com/sukan/oauth2clientz
project_urls =
    Documentation = https://github.com/sukan/oauth2clientz#readme
    Issue Tracker = https://github.com/sukan/oauth2clientz/issues
    Source Code = https://github.com/sukan/oauth2clientz
keywords = oauth2 client
sclassifiers =
    Development Status :: 1 - Planning
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
    Operating System :: OS Independent
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
platforms = any

[options]
python_requires = >=3.6
packages = find:  # use 'find:' to finde packages located in 'package_dir' 
package_dir =
    = src
zip_safe = False

[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.extras_require]
tests =
  pytest
  pytest-cov

code =
  flake8
```

#### pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
# https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setup-cfg-only-projects
requires = [
  "setuptools >= 58",
  "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

if you are on windows and you want to build and publish your package

```
pip install build wheel twine
py -m build -n  # don't forget '-n' flage to force using your project venv
py install -e .  # for editable mode 
py -m twine upload dist/*  # if everything is ok then pulish it on pypi
```

hope that works as it should be.

Comment: thank you very much but in the second command :

`py -m build -n`

is showing this ERROR:

`ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist`

Comment: @ciazrio why you used setup.cfg instead of setup.py?

Comment: #1, i have no clue about the error you got, and i didn't experience it before on windows. 
#2, have a look at this https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html,